# PyTorch | NameError: name 'defaults' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, torch, nameerror, modulenotfounderror, fast-ai

I'm new to `fastai`.

- fastai 2.7.5
- fastcore 1.4.5
- nbdev 1.2.10
- torch 1.12.0
- torchvision 0.13.0

What approaches should I take in trying to resolve such an error like this?

A solution would be greatly appreciated.

Traceback:

```py
(project) daniel@ubuntu-pcs:~/PycharmProjects/project$ python main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/daniel/PycharmProjects/project/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from src.train.train_model import train
  File "/home/daniel/PycharmProjects/project/src/train/train_model.py", line 8, in <module>
    from fastai.vision.all import *
  File "/home/daniel/miniconda3/envs/pdl1lung/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastai/vision/all.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import models
  File "/home/daniel/miniconda3/envs/pdl1lung/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastai/vision/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import xresnet
  File "/home/daniel/miniconda3/envs/pdl1lung/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastai/vision/models/xresnet.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ...torch_basics import *
  File "/home/daniel/miniconda3/envs/pdl1lung/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastai/torch_basics.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .torch_core import *
  File "/home/daniel/miniconda3/envs/pdl1lung/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastai/torch_core.py", line 31, in <module>
    defaults.benchmark = True
NameError: name 'defaults' is not defined
```

---

#### Code

`train_model.py`:

```
...
from fastai.vision.all import *
...
```

Comment: `pip install fastai==1.0.6` but now get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastai.vision.all'`

Comment: `pip install fastai==2.0` but now get `NameError: name 'delegates' is not defined`

Comment: `pip install fastai==2.7.0` but now I get `NameError: name 'defaults' is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
conda create -n venv python==3.6.13
```

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
fastai==2.5.3
fastcore==1.3.27
python==3.6.13
```